# how to make javascript alert work in gmail / outlook

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to make javascript alert work in gmail / outlook, see below code
it's not working how can i do it ,

```
<script>
alert('hiii');
</script>
```

Comment: You are saying that you want to send an email with runnable JavaScript included? You cannot.

Comment: yeah any way to do it

Comment: Nope. At least, I'm yet to come across a mail client that will allow a received email to run JavaScript.

Comment: Certainly not Gmail or Outlook.

Comment: As other's have said, no javascript in email for security reasons. What are you trying to do with the javascript? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: something like when user click image change

Answer (score 2):

Any script placed in an email will be stripped out by most email clients for security reasons.

> Scripting in Emails
>
> The short answer is that scripting is unsupported in emails. This is hardly surprising, given the obvious security risks involved with a script running inside an application that has all that personal information stored in it.
>
> Webmail clients are mostly running the interface in JavaScript and are not keen on your email interfering with that, and desktop client filters often consider JavaScript to be an indicator of spam or phishing emails. Even in the cases where it might run, there really is little benefit to scripting in emails.
>
> Keep your emails as straight HTML and CSS, and avoid the hassle.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/coding/technologies/

If you need to run some script related to the recipient of the email you would need to get them to click a link in the email to open a website to be able to use full JS capabilities.